# Difference between Application.Current.Dispatcher.UnhandledException and Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException

Tags: c#, exception

While reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40295384/7571171), I came across the two different events

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.UnhandledException
```

and

```
Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException
```

and I was wondering what the difference between those two are.

---

My guess is that `Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException` is kind of a wrapper for the `Application.Current.Dispatcher.UnhandledException`, but this is only a gut feeling and I'm very uncertain.

Does it make any difference (for single-threaded or multi-threaded applications)?

Comment: In the same page that you linked to there is an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1472562/2390947) of them.

Comment: @Uran so it appears that `Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException` is actually merely a wrapper around `Application.Current.Dispatcher.UnhandledException` for it to be called from XAML?

Comment: Focus on AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, that is the one you care about since that is the one that tells you that your app crashed hard.

Comment: I would also like to know the answer - the explanation in the linked answer does not explicitly specify if Current.Dispatcher.UnhandledException is the same thing as Current.DispatcherUnhandledException, but if it isn't then something has a very bad name!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between UnhandledException and DispatcherUnhandledException in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212321/difference-between-unhandledexception-and-dispatcherunhandledexception-in-net)